# CodeIgniter syntax

Tags: codeigniter

Here is my code:

```
$this->load->model('login/configurations', '', TRUE);
$data['query'] = $this->configurations->load_data();
```

But my query is not being loaded here:

```
$data['title'] = 'User Area';
$data['main_content'] = 'resources/logged_in_area';
$this->load->view('templates/resources_area', $data);
```

I think it may have to do with the path of my model.  "Login" is the name of the folder "configurations" is in.  The title and main_content variables are loaded into my view.  The resources area template loads my header, footer and nav views.  So I know the last three lines of code are valid.  It's the first three that are not working.

Here is my load_data function:

```
function load_data() {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM configurations WHERE username=" . $this->session->userdata('username'));
    return $query;

   }
```

Anyone have any thoughts?  I get an undefined variable error in my view. ($query)