# Codeigniter returning non-object

Tags: codeigniter

I have this happen all the time and I'm never quite sure why it's happening.  Here is the query in my model:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = "' . $this->session->userdata('email') . '"');
        return $query;
```

I try to output this in my view with:

```
foreach($query->result() as $row) {...echo $row->name, etc.}
```

But I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object ...
```

I ran the profiler and my query is valid and there is data in the database to be pulled.  So what am I do wrong?

Comment: honestly we need more code to adequately assist you.

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714802/codeigniter-problem-retrieving-and-displaying-data-from-db

Comment: No offense, jondavidjohn, but the solution was different.  See the differences between the two accepted solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

**In your model:**

```
function get_members()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = "' . $this->session->userdata('email') . '"');
    return $query->result();
}
```

**In your controller:**

You should then be assigning the data from the database in your controller to your view like so.

```
$data['query'] = $this->yourmodel->get_members(); // Data['query'] will be turned into $query in your view.

$this->load->view('mytemplate', $data);
```

**In your view:**

```
foreach($query as $row) {...echo $row->name, etc.}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the `$query` variable to the view, codeigniter will convert it into a keyed array if it is an object.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

> Note: If you use an object, the class variables will be turned into array elements.

Edit:

In your controller:

```
$query = // do whatever to get the $query.
$members = array();
foreach($query->result() as $row) {
    $members[] = $row;
}
//send $members to view
```

In view:

```
foreach($members as $member) {
    echo $member['name']; // etc
}
```

Comment: So how do I not do that?  I have some similar code to this and it works fine.  What is the proper thing to do.  Newbie here.

Comment: You should execute the query inside of the model or the controller and instead pass an array of model objects or values to the view. The view should just be a dumb data displayer.

Comment: How do I do that?  Sorry for my ignorance.